# How to convert the uncertainty of my pH probe to the uncertainty of my Ka value

Tags: equilibrium

Literally the title. So basically I performed numerous titrations with ethanoic acid sodium hydroxide. I got the full pH curve, and subsequently found the Ka Value of the ethanoic acid. Now here is the issue, I have the uncertainty of the pH probe, which is ±0.1. At the half equivalence point, pKa=pH, so I can safely assume the uncertainty for pKa is also ±0.1.

However, I need to find the uncertainty of the Ka Value I experimentally determined. So I somehow need to convert that ±0.1pKa into the uncertainty for Ka.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just considering the resolution of the pH probe as the only source of error seems unlikely. What about the experiment error? How many times did you do the experiment? What were the values determined?

Answer (score -2):

Following Metron's suggestion, suppose the $p$K$\ce{_a}$ of acetic acid is $4.75 ± 0.1 $. It means that both extreme values of $p$K$\ce{_a}$ are $4.65$ and $4.85$. Corresponding extreme values of K$\ce{_a}$ are $\ce{10^{-4.65} = 2.2 10^{-5}}$ and $\ce{10^{-4.85} = 1.4 10^{-5}}$. As the average of $1.4$ and $2.2$ is $1.8$, the final value for $p$K$\ce{_a}$ is equal to : $1.8 ± 0.4$

Comment: No you shouldn't average the two extremes to get thev estimated value. The estimate for the pKa is $10^{-4.75}$ which happens to be $\ce{1.778... x 10^{-5}}$ which in this case does round to $\ce{1.8 x 10^{-5}}$. My point however is that the difference between the +/- values and the expected value are not symmetric since the scale is logarithmic.